# How to groupBy a typescript array with a Key of an object inside that array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array `products` that needs to be grouped by `Product._shop_id`.

```js
export class Product {
    _id: string;
    _shop_id: string;
}

export class Variant { variant_id: string; }

export interface ShoppingCart {
    Variant: Variant;
    Product: Product;
    quantity: number;
    totalPrice: number;
}

export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    products: ShoppingCart[] = [];

    ngOnInit(){
      this.products = [
                        {Variant: {variant_id: '1'}, Product: {_id: '1', _shop_id:'1'}, quantity: 5, totalPrice: 600},
                        {Variant: {variant_id: '2'}, Product: {_id: '2', _shop_id:'2'}, quantity: 4, totalPrice: 500},
                        {Variant: {variant_id: '5'}, Product: {_id: '3', _shop_id:'2'}, quantity: 3, totalPrice: 400}
                      ]
    }

    someMethod(){
      const productsByShop = this.utils.groupBy(this.products, key);
    }
}
```

Here is the method to achieve this. But I need the Object Key to make it work.

```js
export class Utils {
    constructor() { }

    groupBy(list, key) {
        const map = new Map();
        list.forEach((item) => {
            const collection = map.get(key);
            if (!collection) {
                map.set(key, [item]);
            } else {
                collection.push(item);
            }
        });
        return Array.from(map)[0][1];
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get different arrays grouped by `_shop_id` from `products` array.
Like this:

```
array1: [ {Variant: {variant_id: '1'}, Product: {_id: '1', _shop_id:'1'}, quantity: 5, totalPrice: 600} ]`

array2: [ {Variant: {variant_id: '2'}, Product: {_id: '2', _shop_id:'2'}, quantity: 4, totalPrice: 500},
          {Variant: {variant_id: '5'}, Product: {_id: '3', _shop_id:'2'}, quantity: 3, totalPrice: 400} ]`
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your `_shop_id` belongs to a nested object, you're probably best off passing a lambda to extract it:

```
someMethod(){
  const productsByShop = this.utils.groupBy(this.products,
    (product) => product.Product._shop_id);
}
// ...
export class Utils {
    constructor() { }

    groupBy<T, K>(list: T[], getKey: (item: T) => K) {
        const map = new Map<K, T[]>();
        list.forEach((item) => {
            const key = getKey(item);
            const collection = map.get(key);
            if (!collection) {
                map.set(key, [item]);
            } else {
                collection.push(item);
            }
        });
        return Array.from(map.values());
    }
}
```